# Jquery Toggle Plus/Minus or Slide up/Down in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm displaying data from mysql db

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['showtable']))
{
    $sql = "select * from demo";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {       
    ?> 
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <label idl='<?php echo $row->id;?>'>
                    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="div1" style="display:none;">
                div1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
    exit();
}
```

My requirement is to add jquery toggle or slideup/slidedown after label tag. initally it will be plus sign when i click on plus sign it should open 'div1' with minus sign. i want to put toggle into php while loop so that for each and every row i would be able to get plus toggle for individual row..

Any Help is Appreciated Thanks!

Comment: are you using bootstrap

Comment: @Sasikumar Yes Im using bootstrap Thankx!

Comment: then you can use bootstrap accordion. here is the sample http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion

Answer (score 2):

have a look here :
https://jqueryui.com/toggle/

You need to add jquery and jquery ui to your page. 
After you can follow the example they give, it is the basic use that you need, just create a div after your label to contain your +, and on the toggle convert the + to a -.
Remember to name your div with your id that you used like that

```
<div id="myToggler_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" > + </div>
```

and same to the div that you want to fold / unfold.

If It seems complicated to you, maybe try to integrate a solution like that : 
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/